# stop slider after finish sliding

Tags: jquery

i have a n animate div with left and right arrow , i just want to stop the slider after images finish , the problem that i have is the slider continue going to left and right with empty space , this is my code

> function () {

```
    var size = $("div.slide-here li").size();

    var div_size = size / 4 * 163;
    $('.photo-gallery div.slide-here').css('width', div_size);
    $('.photo-pagging .left-arrow a').click(
        function () {
            $('.photo-gallery div.slide-here').animate({ left: '+=196px' });


            return false;
        });
    $('.photo-pagging .right-arrow a').click(
        function () {
            $('.photo-gallery  div.slide-here').animate({ left: '-=196px' });

            return false;

        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the slider after images finish"? what images need to finish?

Comment: yeah its dynamic slider so i dont know the number of the images ,i just want to stop it or at least loop it when reach to the end

Answer (score 0):

just put in a boundary conditions for the end points by multiplying the image width * the number of images - 1 * - 1 for moving left and 0 for moving right. This would be a check on the first element obviously.

Its hard to be more specific with the given info.

edit: * instead of x for multiplication operator

Comment: yeah i tried that but the animation keep moving after click the button

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question was not clear enough, I suggest you [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) regarding better questions in the future.

Regarding your question, [here](http://designmodo.com/image-slider-jquery-css3/) is a recommended read regarding building a jQuery slider plugin with images.

Good luck!